# to show javascript confirmation box with database fetched values on text changed and then insert or update in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a webform which has unique id...so if that id is already used then I want to ask confirmation from the user, whether he/she wants to update the previous information.
And if the id is not present in the database then insert operation should perform.

Also I want to show the Name and phone in the confirmation box...
Saying the data exist with this Name: and Phone no:

```
    protected void txtTIN_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == true)
    {
        string firm_name = "", place = "", mobile_no = "";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select Tin,Firm_Name,Place,Mobile_No from Cust_details where Tin='" + txtTIN.Text + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        DataTableReader rd = ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            firm_name = rd.GetValue(0).ToString();
            place = rd.GetValue(1).ToString();
            mobile_no = rd.GetValue(2).ToString();
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('This TIN no already has data with Firm Name: ,Place: ,Mobile No: , Do you want to Update?')", true);
            Confirm(sender, e); //this should be a javascript function
            if (confirmValue == "Yes")//if javascript confirmation box returns Yes 
            {
                update(sender, e); //update the values
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("Details.aspx", true);//reload the page
            }
        }
        else
        {
            btnSubmit_Click(sender, e);  //Insert should be performed here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! put your code example that what you try for. and visit link **[How to Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Have a look at these dialog boxes => https://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/

Comment: @ZaheerUlHassan here it is..i have modified